# Android >4.x.x: App with Media Player doesn't play an stream

Tags: android, media-player

I'm writing an Android App which play an Internet Radio Stream. Yesterday i'm update my nexus s from version 2.3 to 4.0.4 and now my app is not running.

that is my code: http://paste.ubuntu.com/936434/

i get this output:

> 04-19 07:01:20.367: D/App(22170): http://stream02.technoloversfm.de/listen.pls?sid=1
>
> 04-19 07:01:29.304: E/MediaPlayer(22170): error (1, -2147483648)
>
> 04-19 07:01:29.308: D/App(22170): java.io.IOException: Prepare failed.: status=0x1
>
> 04-19 07:01:29.312: E/MediaPlayer(22170): start called in state 0
>
> 04-19 06:52:25.980: E/MediaPlayer(21901): Error (-38,0)

whats the problem?

(the internet permission is set)